# Java.How to use multiple variables and iterate over a multiple objects in for loop?

Tags: java

For starters, i'm new in Java

I'm trying like

```
for(forWriting  f : treeSet, forDrawing f2 : treeSet2)
```

but it doesn't work like that

It works only when i use one variable and iterate over a single object, like that

```
for(forWriting  f : treeSet)
```

How can i do it in Java? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What would you like `for(forWriting  f : treeSet, forDrawing f2 : treeSet2)` to mean?

Comment: We can’t answer on how to do it until you explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I have two comparators and two treesets. I want to sort all objects in both treesets and sort them alphabetically. But i can sort only treeset objects in first loop, and then treeset2 objects in second loop

Comment: So the desired outcome is a single alphabetically sorted collection of the contents of both `treeSet` and `treeSet2`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes. How can i do that? Thank you.

Comment: Basically you need to combine the contents of both sets, in some form,  into a single collection and sort that combined collection.  How complicated that will be depends on the details of the two original sets.  For instance, are  the items of `treeSet` and`treeSet2` of the same type, or different types?

Answer (score 1):

It's clear and more readable to don't want to do something like what you are asking.In java you must iterate over a single iterable object using for loop. If the two structures you are iterating into are of the same length you can write a single for loop and get the element from each variable in this way (in pseudo code)

```
for(int i = 0; i< treeSet.Lenght; i++) {
   // get the i-th value from treeSet 
   // get i-th valut from treeSet2

   // ... execute other statements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116386/9406165), you might also want to make sure you 1) iterate over each element and 2) prevent IndexOutOfBound-Exceptions (Pseudo):

```
int max_length = max(treeSet1.length, treeSet2.length);
for(int i = 0; i < max_length; i++) {
    if(i < treeSet1.length) {
        forWriting f = treeSet1.get_by_index(i);
        // Do stuff for forWriting here
    }
    if(i < treeSet2.length) {
        forDrawing f2 = treeSet2.get_by_index(i);
        // Do stuff for forDrawing here
    }
}
```